# POSTGRES datetime2 to timestamp

Tags: postgresql

I am migrating to postgres from sql server. 
Is there a way that I could do the following and have it still work? `SELECT CAST('1/1/2018' AS datetime2)` I have tried and failed with

```
   CREATE TYPE datetime2 AS (date2 TIMESTAMP); --doesn't work
```

Comment: You say you've failed with that code, what is the failure message you're getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have `datetime2` as a synonym for `timestamp` type in PostgreSQL then use domain instead of type:

```
create domain datetime2 as timestamp;
```

Then your cast will work as is:

```
SELECT CAST('1/1/2018' AS datetime2);
┌─────────────────────┐
│      datetime2      │
├─────────────────────┤
│ 2018-01-01 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```

Except the name it will have same behavior as original `timestamp` type.

What you are doing in your question is to create [composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) (record with single field `date2` of `timestamp` type) which could be also highly useful but for another kinds of tasks.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is:

```
SELECT '1/1/2018' AS TIMESTAMP;

  timestamp 
 -----------
  1/1/2018
```

Or

```
SELECT CAST('1/1/2018' AS TIMESTAMP); 

      timestamp      
 ---------------------
  2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

Or

```
SELECT CAST('1/1/2018' AS DATE);

    date    
------------
 2018-01-01
```

It depends really on what you want to do.